# Max dimension of a subspace of singular $n\times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am sure the answer to this is (kind of) well known. I've searched the web and the site for a proof and found nothing, and if this is a duplicate, I'm sorry.

The following question was given in a contest I took part. I had an approach but it didn't solve the problem.

> Consider $V$ **a** linear subspace of the real vector space $\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R})$ ($n\times n$ real entries matrices) such that $V$ contains only singular matrices (i.e matrices with determinant equal to $0$). What is the maximal dimension of $V$?

A quick guess would be $n^2-n$ since if we consider $W$ the set of $n\times n$ real matrices with last line equal to $0$ then this space has dimension $n^2-n$ and it is a linear space of singular matrices.

Now the only thing there is to prove is that if $V$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R})$ of dimension $k > n^2-n$ then $V$ contains a non-singular matrix. The official proof was unsatisfactory for me, because it was a combinatorial one, and seemed to have few things in common with linear algebra. I was hoping for a pure linear algebra proof.

My approach was to search for a permutation matrix in $V$, but I used some 'false theorem' in between, which I am ashamed to post here.

Comment: I'm a little curious about the combinatorial proof myself.

Comment: I'll try and write it once I remember it. :)

Comment: I am looking forward to it too. What's the basis for singular matrices then?

Comment: Some relevant papers: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.0298 ; http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.1615&rep=rep1&type=pdf ; http://www.math.technion.ac.il/~meshulam/eprints/maxrank.pdf. The first published proofs seem to be in J. Dieudonné, Sur une généralisation du groupe orthogonal à quatre variables, Arch. Math., 1 (1949) 282-287 and H. Flanders, On spaces of linear transformations with bounded rank, J. Lond. Math. Soc., 37 (1962) 10-16; I couldn't find either of those two with free access.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

We can show more generally that if $\mathcal M$ is a linear subspace of $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that all its element have a rank less than or equal to $p$, where $1\leq p<n$, then the dimension of $\mathcal M$ is less than or equal to $np$. To see that, consider the subspace $\mathcal E:=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&B\\^tB&A\end{pmatrix}, A\in\mathcal M_{n-p}(\mathbb R),B\in\mathcal M_{p,n-p}(\mathbb R) \right\}$. Its dimension is $p(n-p)+(n-p)^2=(n-p)(p+n-p)=n(n-p)$. Let $\mathcal M$ a linear subspace of $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $\displaystyle\max_{M\in\mathcal M}\operatorname{rank}(M)=p$. We can assume that this space contains the matrix $J:=\begin{pmatrix}I_p&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$. Indeed, if $M_0\in\mathcal M$ is such that $\operatorname{rank}M_0=p$, we can find $P,Q\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ invertible matrices such that $J=PM_0Q$, and the map $\varphi\colon \mathcal M\to\varphi(\mathcal M)$ defined by $\varphi(M)=PMQ$ is a rank-preserving bijective linear map.

If we take $M\in\mathcal M\cap \mathcal E$, then we can show, considering $M+\lambda J\in\mathcal M$, that $M=0$. Therefore, since
$$\dim (\mathcal M+\mathcal E)=\dim(\mathcal M)+\dim(\mathcal E)\leq \dim(\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R))=n^2, $$
we have 
$$\dim (\mathcal M)\leq n^2-n(n-p)=np.$$

Comment: I have one question: Why can we assume that $J \in \mathcal{M}$?

Comment: @beni: we can find a matrix $M_0\in\mathcal M$ whose rank is $p$. Now, we take $P\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ invertible such that $J=PM_0P^{-1}$, and we consider the map $\varphi\colon \mathcal M\to\varphi(\mathcal M)$ defined by $\varphi(M)= PMP^{-1}$. It's an isomorphism, hence $\varphi(\mathcal M)$ and $\mathcal M$ have the same dimension.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Ok. Now is clear.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo How can we prove easily that $rank(M+λJ)\leq p$ for all $\lambda$ implies $M=0$? I see a proof computing the $p+1$ minors via the Schur complement, is there some cleaner argument?

Comment: @JoseBrox I considered the same thing, here's what I came up with.  We have
$$
M = \pmatrix{0 & B\\B^T & A} \neq 0; \qquad 
\lambda J + M = \pmatrix{\lambda I & B\\B^T & A}.
$$
If $\lambda \neq 0$, we can [apply block row/column operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) to show that $M + \lambda J$ has the same rank as
$$
\pmatrix{\lambda I & 0\\0 & A - \frac{B^TB}{\lambda}}.
$$
The rank of this matrix is $p + \operatorname{rk}(A - \frac{B^TB}{\lambda})$, so it suffices to show that there exists a non-zero $\lambda$ such that $A - \frac{B^TB}{\lambda} \neq 0$.

Comment: An important detail in the above: if $B$ is non-zero, then so is $B^TB$.  In fact, $B$ and $B^TB$ necessarily have the same rank.

Comment: The name seems to me very Italian :-) Congratulations on the profile.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo,In your reply to  Beni  you certainly mean $\exists P,Q\in GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ such that $J=PM_0Q$. That's what you explained in your answer. $M_0$ and $J$ have the same rank but they are not necessarily similar. Thank you very much for your eminent response.