# Let $A$ be a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(F)$, prove that if $\dim(A)> n^2-n$ , $\exists$ invertible matrix $M \in A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(F)$, prove that if $\dim(A)> n^2-n$ , $\exists$ invertible matrix M $\in$ $A$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66877/max-dimension-of-a-subspace-of-singular-n-times-n-matrices

Comment: I posted an answer to the question of which it was marked as a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2045640/9911