# What is the maximum dimension of space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

**Problem**

Let $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space of square matrix with size $n \times n$. Assume $V$ is a subspace of $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such, that all its elements have zero determinant.
What is the maximum dimension of space $V$?

**Question**

Can somebody give me a hint on how to tackle the problem above? Thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66877/max-dimension-of-a-subspace-of-singular-n-times-n-matrices

Comment: Thanks @cmk. Looks like my question duplicates the one from your link.

Comment: No problem! $\ $