# $\operatorname{Span}_k\{A_1,\ldots, A_l\}\cap GL_n(k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $A_1,\ldots, A_l\in M_n(k)$ be square matrices. Is there any way to determine if $\operatorname{Span}_k\{A_1,\ldots, A_l\}\cap GL_n(k)$ is empty or not?

I am adding more details about the specific cases that I am interested in:

I am interested in the case when $k$ is a finite field. Also, all the $A_i$'s are of the form $$    \left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
        C_{11} & C_{12} & \cdots & C_{1m} \\ \hline
        C_{21} & C_{22} & \cdots & C_{2m} \\ \hline
        \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\ \hline
        C_{m1} & C_{m2} & \cdots & C_{mm} 
    \end{array}
    \right]$$
with exactly one block $C_{ij}$ being non-zero.

The dimension for each $C_{ij}$ is given, and each $A_i$ is also given. I am interested in how to determine if $\operatorname{span}\{A_1,\ldots, A_l\}\cap GL_n(k)$ is empty or not. Is there any algorithms with polynomial complexity to determine this?

Comment: It is most certainly not empty. $A_{1}\dots\,A_{l}$ are square matrices which means there will be certain square matrices which are invertible. Therefore the intersection of all square matrices with invertible square matrices will be non-empty and will consist of all invertible linear square matrices.

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC: what if $n=2$, $l = 1$ and $A_1 = \left(\matrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}\right)$?

Comment: By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66936/81360), if the span is $n^2 - n + 1$-dimensional with $k \in \{\Bbb R, \Bbb C\}$, the intersection must be non-empty.

Comment: I meant to say if the span is *at least* $n^2 - n + 1$-dimensional