# $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\dim(V)\geq kn+1.$ How to show that there exist $ A\in V$ and $r(A)\geq k+1?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

$V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\dim(V)\geq kn+1.$ How to show that there exist $ A\in V$ and $r(A)\geq k+1?$

I want to find the maximal dimension of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that all members of it are not invertible. I think the problem above may help,but I don't know how to prove it.Any help will be thanked.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66936/81360)

Comment: What is $r(A)$?

Comment: @Bernard Presumably the rank.  Note that the question was tagged as being related to rank.

Comment: The rank of a vector???

Comment: @Bernard $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$, and so is a set of matrices.  Of course every element of $V$ has a rank.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Of course. I hadn't realised that $\mathbf R^{n\times n}$ might denote here the space of square matrices of order  $n$ (which I usually denote $M_n(\mathbf R)$).