# Dimension of a Subspace of $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{W})$ Consisting of Only Linear Transformations of Rank $\leq r$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

**Background.**  I have a conjecture (stated in two ways below), which I would like to see whether it is true (both the inequality part and the part involving the equality cases).  The motivation comes from this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3396072).  The conjecture (both the inequality part and the equality cases) is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66877) to be true when the base field $\mathbb{K}$ has the property that, for any positive integer $l$, the only solution $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_l)\in\mathbb{K}^l$ to
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_l^2=0$$
is $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_l=0$.  Subfields of $\mathbb{R}$ are examples, but there are other fields with this property such as pure transcendental extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ and ordered fields.  (They are all fields of characteristic $0$, by the way.)

> **Conjecture (Version I).** Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field.  Let $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ be two finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{K}$ with dimensions $n$ and $m$, respectively.  For an integer $r$ such that $$0\leq r\leq \min\{m,n\}\,,$$ suppose that $\mathcal{T}$ is a subspace of the $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{W})$ such that every linear transformation $\varphi:\mathcal{V}\to \mathcal{W}$ in $\mathcal{T}$ is of rank at most $r$.  Then, $$\dim_\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{T})\leq r\,\max\{m,n\}\,.$$
>
> Here are the equality cases.
>
> (a) For $m< n$, there exists an $r$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{I}$ of $\mathcal{W}$ such that $\mathcal{T}$ consists of linear transformations $\varphi$ such that $\text{im}(\varphi)\subseteq \mathcal{I}$.
>
> (b) For $m>n$, there exists an $(n-r)$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{K}$ of $\mathcal{V}$ such that $\mathcal{T}$ consists of linear transformations $\varphi$ such that $\ker(\varphi)\supseteq \mathcal{K}$.
>
> (c) For $m=n$, there are two possibilities.
>
> - There exists an $r$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{I}$ of $\mathcal{W}$ such that $\mathcal{T}$ consists of linear transformations $\varphi$ such that $\text{im}(\varphi)\subseteq \mathcal{I}$.
> - There exists an $(n-r)$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{K}$ of $\mathcal{V}$ such that $\mathcal{T}$ consists of linear transformations $\varphi$ such that $\ker(\varphi)\supseteq \mathcal{K}$.

> **Conjecture (Version II).** Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field.  For integers $m,n>0$ and $r$ such that $$0\leq r\leq \min\{m,n\}\,,$$ suppose that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector subspace of the $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $\text{Mat}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ such that each matrix in $\mathcal{M}$ is of rank at most $r$.  Then, $$\dim_\mathbb{K}(\mathcal{M})\leq r\,\max\{m,n\}\,.$$
>
> Here are the equality cases.
>
> (a) For $m< n$, there exists an $r$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathbb{K}^m$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ consists of matrices whose column spaces are contained in $\mathcal{C}$.
>
> (b) For $m> n$, there exists an $r$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{R}$ of $\mathbb{K}^n$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ consists of matrices whose row spaces are contained in $\mathcal{R}$.
>
> (c) For $m=n$, there are two possibilites.
>
> - There exists an $r$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathbb{K}^m$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ consists of matrices whose column spaces are contained in $\mathcal{C}$.
> - There exists an $r$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{R}$ of $\mathbb{K}^n$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ consists of matrices whose row spaces are contained in $\mathcal{R}$.

**Warning.**  While I am quite confident that the inequality is true, I am not very sure that I got the equality cases right.  If there are counterexamples, I would love to see.

**Remark.**  I just noticed that [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) posted [this reference](http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~meshulam/eprints/maxrank.pdf) under the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66877).  I have not yet digested it, but it <s>seems</s> says that the inequality holds when $m=n$ for any field $\mathbb{K}$.  Maybe, the proof can be modified to allow $m\neq n$.  <s>There does not seem to be any mention of the equality cases in this paper.</s>  Theorem 3 of the paper gives the equality condition.

**Edit.** The conjecture (both the inequality part and the equality cases) is true when $m=n$.  Now, we have to find out what to do when $m\neq n$.  By the way, using duality or transpose, we may assume that $m<n$.  (Perhaps, we can even allow $\mathbb{K}$ to be a division ring.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noticed, part (c) of your conjecture is already known, and
the others parts can easily be reduced to it.

**Proof of (a)**  : Suppose that $n \gt m$. The, we have $r \leq m$ and a subpace ${\cal T} \subseteq Hom({\cal V},{\cal W})$ such that ${\mathsf{rank(t}})\leq r$ for every $t\in T$. Let ${\cal W}'$ be a space of dimension $n-m$ and such that  ${\cal W}\cap {\cal W}' =\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. You can view $\cal T$ as a subpace of
$Hom({\cal V},{\cal W} \oplus {\cal W}')$, to which part (c) applies.

If we were in the second case of (c), $\cal T$ would be isomorphic to a subpace of $Hom({\cal V}',{\cal W})$ where ${\cal V}'$ is a $r$-dimensional quotient of $\cal V$, whence $\dim({\cal T}) \leq rm \lt rn$, which contradicts the hypothesis.

So we must be in the first case of (c), and there is a $r$-dimensional ${\cal I} \subseteq {\cal W} \oplus {\cal W}'$ such that $\cal T \subseteq Hom({\cal V},I)$ ; we may assume that ${\cal I}\subseteq {\cal W}$ by replacing $\cal I$ with ${\cal I}\cap {\cal W}$, and then we are done.

**Proof of (b)**  : Suppose that $n \lt m$. The, we have $r \leq n$ and a subpace ${\cal T} \subseteq Hom({\cal V},{\cal W})$ such that $\mathsf{rank}(t)\leq r$ for every $t\in T$. Let ${\cal V}'$ be a space of dimension $m-n$ and such that  ${\cal V}\cap {\cal V}' =\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Extending any $t\in\cal T$ by zero on ${\cal V}'$, you can view $\cal T$ as a subpace of $Hom({\cal V} \oplus {\cal V}',{\cal W})$, to which part (c) applies.

If we were in the second case of (c), there would be a $r$-dimensional ${\cal I} \subseteq {\cal W}$ such that $\mathsf{Im}(t)\subseteq {\cal I}$ for any $t\in T$. But then $\cal T$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $Hom({\cal V},{\cal I})$, whence $\dim({\cal T}) \leq rn \lt rm$, which contradicts the hypothesis.

So we must be in the second case of (c), and there is a $r$-dimensional $K \subseteq {\cal V} \oplus {\cal V}'$ such that every $t\in\cal T$ is zero on $\cal K$ ; we can assume that ${\cal K}\supseteq {\cal V}'$ by replacing $\cal K$ with ${\cal K}+ {\cal V}'$, and then we are done.