# How can we compute $|\mathrm{Aut}(M)|$ from a basis for $\mathrm{End}(M)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, finite-fields, abelian-categories

For a finite field $\mathbf{k}$ with $|\mathbf{k}|=q$, and an object $M$ of a $\mathbf{k}$-linear category, suppose we have finite basis for $\mathrm{End}(M)$. How can we compute the size of $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$? What do we need to know about those basis elements to compute this?

Comment: With a result along [these lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66936/81360) (or more precisely, along the lines of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.0298.pdf) for instance), we could produce lower bounds for the size of $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ using only the dimension of $\operatorname{End}(M)$, assuming that the homs are maps over finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Otherwise, you are essentially counting solutions to $\det(x_1 f_1 + \cdots + x_n f_n) = 0$, assuming once again that $M$ is a finite dimensional space.