# Find eigenvalues of linear operator $X \mapsto AX^TA$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Matrix $A$ has $n$ distinct non-zero eigenvalues, $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$. Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the linear operator $$ L : X \mapsto AX^{T}A $$

---

I tried to use a decomposition: $A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal matrix with $\lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n$ on its diagonal. Then, I wrote equation $L : (PXP^{-1})^{T} \rightarrow P\Lambda X\Lambda P^{-1} = \lambda (PXP^{-1})^{T}$. So, I've got $C\Lambda X\Lambda C^{-1} = \lambda X^{T}$, where $C= P^{T}P$ and stuck there.

 Edited: $X, A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$

Comment: What makes you think that a closed form for this operator given the information above is enough to proceed? Does $X$ or $A$ have any other properties? At the moment this seems similar to asking what eigenvalues of $AB$ are given you know eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: @Gregory It seems to me that $L$ is a linear map from the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices to itself and the question is about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this linear map, i.e., we are trying to solve $AX^\top A = \lambda X$.

Comment: @Gregory Matrixes $A, X \in \mathbb C^{n\times n} $

Comment: I suspect that the eigenvalues of $A$ are not enough to determine the eigenvalues of this linear operator.

Comment: Since $A$ is invertible, so is $L$. So, by taking determinants on both sides of $AX^TA=\lambda X$, we at least know that $\lambda$ is an $n$-th root of $\det(A)^2$ **if** $X$ is invertible.

Comment: @Paravozik: The linear map in the OP is in essence a linear map from $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ to itself. $A$ as a square matrix of dimension $n$ has at most $n$ different eigen values. Where are, the matrix representing the operator in the OP (writing $n\times n$-matirces as $n^2$-vectors has potentially $n^2$ different eigenvalues. Thus, as Ben Grossmann said, it would to be surprising if the eigenvalues if $A$ in general provide all the information about the Eigen-values of $L$.

Comment: Is the sup-T meaning to take $X$-transpose? Or to take $A$-transpose? Please clarify?

Comment: @paulgarrett $X^T$ means to take $X$-transpose

Comment: Ok, thanks, ... sometimes people do write the sup-T on the left... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the eigenvalues of $A$ are insufficient to determine the eigenvalues of $L$. As an example, consider the cospectral matrices
$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{array}\right), \quad 
B = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\0&2 \end{array}\right).
$$
We find that the eigenvalues of $X \mapsto AX^TA$ are $\pm 2, 1, 4$, whereas the eigenvalues of $X \mapsto BX^TB$ are $\pm 2, 3 \pm \sqrt{5}$. The corresponding eigenvectors of $B$ are
$$
-2: \pmatrix{1&-3\\3&1}\qquad
2: \pmatrix{-1&-1\\-1&1}\\
3 - \sqrt{5}: 
\pmatrix{3\sqrt{5} + 7 & -\sqrt{5}-1\\
-2\sqrt{5}-4&2}\qquad
3 + \sqrt{5}:
\pmatrix{7-3\sqrt{5} & \sqrt{5}-1\\
2\sqrt{5}-4& 2}
$$
It is interesting that the eigenvectors associated with $3 \pm \sqrt{5}$ are non-invertible.

If $A$ is real and symmetric, then the eigenvalues of $L$ can be deduced. In particular, $L$ will have eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ with associated eigenvector $xx^T$ (where $Ax = \lambda_j x$) and $\pm \lambda_j\lambda_k$ with associated eigenvector $xy^T \pm yx^T$ (where $Ax = \lambda_j x$ and $Ay = \lambda_k y$).

*Note 1:* From experiment, it seems that $\pm \det(A)$ is an eigenvalue in the case that $A$ has size $2 \times 2$; I'm not sure why this would be the case.

*Note 2:* By the [result described on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66936/81360), a sum of eigenspaces that contains no invertible elements can have dimension at most $n^2 - n$. One the other hand, by user1551's comment, it holds that if $X$ is an invertible eigenvector of $L$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then it must be that $\lambda^{n} = \det(A)^2$. I suspect that these ideas can be combined in an interesting way.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the first approach. You get $AX^TA=\lambda_1\lambda_2 X^T$, which is not a multiple of $X$ in general.

Comment: @MaoWao You're right; I've fixed my answer.

Comment: If there's interest, I could add some code in matlab or python that produce the eigenvalues of interest.

Comment: @user8675309 You're right, the last part of my answer is definitely wrong then. Editing that out