# What is the largest linear subspace contained within the rank 2 variety of 3x3 real matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry

I know it's possible to get a 3-dimensional subspace by using the skew-symmetric matrices, but is it possible to get anything larger than that? How would I go about proving there is no 4-dimensional subspace?

Edit: To clarify, by rank 2 variety I mean the variety of matrices with rank<=2, i.e. det(M)=0.

Comment: What about matrices with zero first column?

Comment: @Sasha Thanks, I don't know how I forgot about that.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66877/max-dimension-of-a-subspace-of-singular-n-times-n-matrices?noredirect=1&lq=1). The maximal possible dimension in this case is $3^2 - 3 = 6$; Sasha's comment above is an example of such a subspace with this dimension. For $n \times n$ matrices, the largest subspace contained in the subspace of singular $n\times n$ matrices has dimension $n^2 - n$.